# Custom kafka connector is not detected

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, jar, apache-kafka-connect

I don't have internet access so I am not able to use Maven to build or package the custom kafka connector.

I am trying to plugin the custom connector but it is not getting added to connector list. I am sure that PluginClassLoader is detecting the connector path but it is not adding the connector. Is there any folder structure or anything i need to follow or do i have to specify any parameters while building the jar file.
Below is the picture of the connect log

[image]

Comment: Did you actually build a JAR? Or did you just put class/java files into some folder? Maven doesn't need internet to package/compile code, only to download dependencies... I'd like to point out that JMS connectors already exist

Comment: I am creating a tibco-jms connector which is there on confluent but it needs confluent license and we are using cloudera kafka setup. Hence creating custom connector

Comment: Have you looked at Apache Camel Connectors as an alternative? Regardless, you didn't answer the rest of my question. Clearly the folder is found, but it found no classes in there that implement the SourceConnector interface

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue actually jar was not built properly I have created INDEX.list file under META-INF which mention the class path